# Is there a word for "unnecessitate"?

Tags: verbs

I'm looking for a **verb for making something unnecessary**. Unnecessitate does not sound right. Alternatives?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to ELL. Please construct a sentence showing how you'd like to use it.  Do you mean "{transitive verb} {direct object [the thing no longer necessary]}"?

Answer (score 2):

Considering the fact that you have provided no context in which the word you're looking for is going to be used, the verb [**to obviate**](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/obviate) is all I can suggest. It fits your description precisely:

> To obviate something such as a problem or a need means to remove it or make it unnecessary.

Example sentence:

> Our old-fashioned push-mower, for instance, **obviates** the needs for extension leads.

Answer (score 1):

A simple verb to use is, depending on your context, might be

> **replace**
>
> The automobile **replaced** the horse and buggy making the latter unnecessary.